# Why is an L1-estimator a special case of an M-estimator?

Tags: regression, estimation

An L1 estimator minimizes the absolute difference between $Y$ and $x\beta$, whereas an M-estimator minimizes some function of the residuals. But the objective function needs to be differentiable right? Then why is an L1-estimator a special case of M-estimator?

Comment: Why do you suppose an objective function has to be differentiable?  And why do you (implicitly) assume all M-estimators are based on differentiable functions?  I think a closer examination of these assumptions may lead you to the answer you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Why do you suppose an objective function has to be differentiable? And why do you (implicitly) assume all M-estimators are based on differentiable functions? I think a closer examination of these assumptions may lead you to the answer you seek. – whuber